# How can I customize/disable notification bubbles?

Tags: notification, notify-osd

Is there a way you can disable or customize the notification bubbles on Lucid?

[image]

Comment: N.B. With rhythmbox's notifications on which songs are playing, disable the Notification plugin.

Answer (score 22):

Yes you can, using a tool called [Notify OSD Configuration](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/06/customize-the-ubuntu-notification-bubbles/).

If you want to disable  them rename the file
 `/usr/share/dbus-1/services/org.freedesktop.Notifications.service`:

```
sudo mv /usr/share/dbus-1/services/org.freedesktop.Notifications.service{,.disabled}
```

To re-enable:

```
sudo mv /usr/share/dbus-1/services/org.freedesktop.Notifications.service{.disabled,}
```

You need to restart your computer after either one of these changes for them to take effect.

Comment: This tool presume that you patch your original notify ost libraries, and you cannot disable them. I wouldn't recommend this.

Comment: @OpenNingia, using a patched NotifyOSD is necessary because the default doesn't allow any configuration. Edited my answer to show how to disable them entirely.

Comment: This didn't work for me on Ubuntu 12.04. I executed your first command and then promptly received a notification seconds later from Spotify.

Comment: @KamilSlowikowski , you may need to reboot

Comment: wooow, I'm not sure if that worked, but that syntax you're using in mv will change my life forever.

Comment: Restarting the computer is **never** the correct way to activate, enable, shut down or disable a service on Linux.

Comment: @Teekin unless systemd gets wedged as PID 1

Answer (score 8):

To alter these settings, install `gconf-editor` from the software-center.

Scroll to `/ ▸ apps  ▸ nm-applet`  and check `disable-connected-notifications` and `disable-disconnected-notifications` settings there. Check the attached image for clarifications.

[image]

As For the VLC, you need to visit VLC Preferences (Press Ctrl + P, or access it from tools Menu)

And Disable *SysTray Popup when Minimized* (Hover the move over that option and read the descripton)

[image]

Comment: I was searching how to turn them off in vlc. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

You can also turn off particular notification.To turn off pidgin notification,Open pidgin-->Tools--->Plugins

Uncheck **libnotify popups** there..

[image]

To **turn off notify-osd notifications**,type the following in terminal and restart your system.

```
sudo mv /usr/share/dbus-1/services/org.freedesktop.Notifications.service /usr/share/dbus-1/services/org.freedesktop.Notifications.service.disabled
```

To **disable rythmbox song pop up notification**:

Go to:

Edit -> Plugins

and uncheck the **Status Icon** plugin.

Another way:

Edit --> Plugins

Select Status Icon, click the **configure** button

Choose the **never shown** option for notifications.

Comment: Thanks. However, the one piece of software I would _really_ want to disable notifications for is Banshee,  but there doesn't seem to be any options for that at all, unless I'm _really_ missing something.

Answer (score 4):

You can stop song change popup notification form this

1. Open Rhythmbox see in Menu: Edit -> Plagins (open it)
2. Uncheck Notification plugin

[image: Image Link]

Answer (score 2):

The question

[How to turn off the pop up notification in 12.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/130210/how-to-turn-off-the-pop-up-notification-in-12-04)

was redirected here but this question's context is framed for lucid 10.04 which uses `notification-daemon` and not Pangolin 12.04 which uses `notify-osd` (On Screen Display) to make pop-up bubbles.

This can be seen in the 12.04 system file (NB 10.04 predates this):

```
view-source:file:///usr/share/dbus-1/services/org.freedesktop.Notifications.service
```

with **`notifying`** content uniquely specific to either the `Unity` or `Gnome` default interface:

```
[D-BUS Service]
Name=org.freedesktop.Notifications
Exec=/bin/sh -c 'if
     [ ! -x /usr/lib/notification-daemon/notification-daemon ] ||
     [ "$GDMSESSION" = guest-restricted ] ||
     [ "$GDMSESSION" = gnome-classic-guest-restricted ]
     [ "$GDMSESSION" = default -a
          "$(basename `readlink /etc/alternatives/x-session-manager`)" =
                gnome-session ] ||
     [ "$GDMSESSION" = ubuntu ] ||
     [ "$GDMSESSION" = ubuntu-2d ];
  then exec /usr/lib/notify-osd/notify-osd;
  else exec /usr/lib/notification-daemon/notification-daemon; fi'
```

What follows is explicitly for the 12.04 redirected question.

The complete stack of pending notifications can be disabled and cleared using a terminal window
(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and entering

```
killall notify-osd
```

after which notifications resume.

To disable for an arbitrary length of time use:

```
dbus-monitor "interface='org.freedesktop.Notifications'" |             \
grep --line-buffered "member=Notify"                     |             \
sed -u -e  's/.*/killall notify-osd/g'                   |             \
bash
```

This crude solution can be stopped by closing the terminal window or typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

Change `"member=Notify"` to customize the desired selection of notifications for purging.

For more control see:
[Can org.freedesktop.Notifications.CloseNotification(uint id) be triggered and invoked via DBus?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/190406/can-org-freedesktop-notifications-closenotificationuint-id-be-triggered-and-in/280751#280751)

Other techniques are documented in the references.

ref.:

- [How to disable notification from network-manager](https://askubuntu.com/questions/67500/how-to-disable-notification-from-network-manager)
- [Is it possible to block NotifyOSD for one application?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56390/is-it-possible-to-block-notifyosd-for-one-application/192689#192689)
- [filter messages to "notification area" applet](https://askubuntu.com/questions/298149/filter-messages-to-notification-area-apple)
- [How can I customize/disable notification bubbles?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13464/how-can-i-customize-disable-notification-bubbles)

Answer (score 1):

This script toggles the notify-osd notifications: (inspired by https://askubuntu.com/a/35840/17940)

```
$ cat toggle-notify.sh

# Disable libnotify notification bubbles that appear in the top-right corner
# of your screen. Works on Ubuntu 12.04.
disabled=$HOME/notify-osd-disabled
if [ -e $disabled ]
then
  echo "Enabled notify-osd"
  sudo chmod +x /usr/lib/notify-osd/notify-osd
  rm -f $disabled
else
  echo "Disabled notify-osd"
  sudo chmod -x /usr/lib/notify-osd/notify-osd
  killall notify-osd 2>/dev/null
  touch $disabled
fi
```

It works on:

- Ubuntu 12.04
- Ubuntu 14.04

Make it executable and run it:

```
$ chmod +x toggle-notify.sh

$ ./toggle-notify.sh 
Disabled notify-osd
```

### Keyboard shortcut

You can bind a keyboard shortcut to this script:

```
$ mkdir ~/bin
$ mv toggle-notify.sh ~/bin
$ export PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To disable the Notification bubbles you can remove the 'Notification Area' item from the panel. Just right click on the notification area item and select 'Remove From Panel'.

*UPDATE: The Notification Area will be no more from Ubuntu 11.04*

Comment: I don't want to get rid of the notification area entirely, but only the bubbles.

Answer (score 0):

go to package manager and remove pop-up notification ;; it will auto install another that the system needs .BUT will not show a pop-up window when a new song comes on . 
did this to mine mint 16 mate.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried all of the methods listed here, and none worked in Fedora 18.  Eventually I found something that worked (copy-pasted from http://www.superuser.com/questions/543064/how-to-disable-all-gnome-3-notifications):

---

> > I have several systems from which I don't want update or other messages. I would prefer to just check logs.

Unless you want to go into each program (i.e. Network settings » Disable Notifications), yet still get system messages, you could:

```
su -
chmod 000 /usr/libexec/notification-daemon
reboot
```

This should work on most GNOME3 systems to kill all messages.

---

Hope it saves someone hours of searching.

Comment: why Fedora on AskUbuntu? Why Fedora18, when it is EOL?

Comment: I found no thread on the internet asking this question for anything outside of Ubuntu, other than the one I referenced.  I think the same behavior should occur on other versions of Fedora also; I just put 18 because that's what I have.