# Shortcut to hide libnotify

Tags: shortcut-keys, libnotify

I was wondering if it is possible to make an shortcut to hide all those Notify Bubbles (libnotify) for some time. Why I'am ask this? Because sometimes I want to see something, read or even show and page for someone and those bubbles bother a little bit. So if it is possible, will be really cool :)

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I dont think there is a direct way to disable and re-enable the notifications.

However you could write two scripts which you could have on your desktop or a dock such as awn/docky etc.  The scripts would remove the execute permission from the executable that is run to display the notification.  You also need to kill the notification process that is running.

one script - lets call it "disableNotify" could have the commands

```
sudo chmod -x /usr/lib/notify-osd/notify-osd
killall notify-osd
```

the other script - lets call it "enableNotify" could have the commands

```
sudo chmod +x /usr/lib/notify-osd/notify-osd
```

Create each script as a text file in Text Editor

Give the script execute rights i.e.

```
chmod +x enableNotify
chmod +x disableNotify
```

The scripts will obviously prompt you for your password since it uses "sudo".  There are ways to prevent this but that is perhaps worth another question.

Comment: Thanks. This just what I was looking for. Now I will look how I make to execute using the Xterm, to don't have to open terminal and use sudo ./disableNotify all the time. :)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I made a [script](https://gist.github.com/slowkow/daa7d225674778b58196) with fossfreedom's commands to toggle notify-osd notifications on Ubuntu 12.04. I also show how to bind it to a keyboard shortcut in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/474215/17940).