# How to turn off Libnotify notifications only when sound is in muted state?

Tags: sound, libnotify

I have a multimedia keyboard that allows me to easily mute the sound (Ubuntu 12.04). It would be nice to "link" this to also turn off libnotify messages that pop-up in the top right corner (i.e. Pidgin messages).

So when Ubuntu is muted, no libnotify messages would pop up. When not muted, messages show as normal.

Is this possible with a script of some kind or would it require changing source code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See my script on [github](https://gist.github.com/slowkow/daa7d225674778b58196).

[This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/474215/17940) includes a script to toggle notify-osd notifications on Ubuntu 12.04, and shows how to bind it to a keyboard shortcut.

Related:

- [Shortcut to hide libnotify](https://askubuntu.com/q/35815/17940)
- [How can I customize/disable notification bubbles?](https://askubuntu.com/q/13464/17940)

Answer (score 1):

It would require changing the source code of `notify-osd` to turn off all notifications (or at least, to filter some; you may want to keep the sound/brightness/etc… notifications active for example, or urgent ones).

Outside of changing the source code of notify-osd (the daemon which runs in the user session and handles the display of the notifications), there is no way to disable all notifications like this.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try two approaches if I needed this facility.

**Option 1:**

Bind the key that does the mute to a script. This is a simple approach and removes any complication of knowing the inards of libnotify

**Option 2:**

Run a cron job that runs every second to interrogate the state of pulse audio and then disable or enable libnotify.
I haven't given you detailed instructions, but sometimes some ideas can get you on the right track. I have done neither of these so I can't give you a step by step but the concepts are not out of the realm of impossibility.

By the way its a great idea! I will stick it on my things to do one I get the time as it's a great idea :)

Comment: adding this answer back in as it was deleted.