# How to turn off the pop up notification in 12.04?

Tags: notification

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I customize/disable notification bubbles?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13464/how-can-i-customize-disable-notification-bubbles)

How can I turn off the pop up notification that comes at the top right corner each time when I get connected to the internet/wi-fi or when the songs in vlc playlist changes?

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04, Gnome classic.