# How do I disable the sound indicator notification bubbles?

Tags: notification, notify-osd

I have Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. Every time I press the volume up/down/mute button on my keyboard, this box appears in the top right corner of my screen telling me the current volume level. Is there any way to disable that box from appearing?

Comment: You can check this post for recent Ubuntu versions:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1044599/hide-or-remove-gnome-pop-up-for-sound-volume-level-indicator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, this is option is not available as user configuration. You need to change & rebuild source of `media-keys.gnome-settings-plugin` (`libmedia-keys.so`)  from `unity-settings-daemon` package.

If you want disable all notification, then this is a duplicate. See [How can I customize/disable notification bubbles?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13464/how-can-i-customize-disable-notification-bubbles)

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 64bit.

1. Download build dependences & source:

   ```
   sudo apt-get build-dep unity-settings-daemon
   apt-get source unity-settings-daemon
   ```
2. Modify `gsd-media-keys-manager.c` to disable volume notification only

   ```
   unity-settings-daemon-14.04.0+14.04.20140606/
   nano plugins/media-keys/gsd-media-keys-manager.c
   ```

   Use `//` to comment those two lines then `return TRUE;`:

   ```
   static gboolean
   ubuntu_osd_notification_show_volume (GsdMediaKeysManager *manager,
                                        gint value,
                                        gboolean muted)
   {
           //return ubuntu_osd_do_notification (&manager->priv->volume_notification,
           //                                   "volume", value, muted, volume_icons);
           return TRUE;
   }
   ```
3. Compile & replace the one from repository:

   ```
   ./autogen.sh
   make
   sudo cp /usr/lib/unity-settings-daemon-1.0/libmedia-keys.so /usr/lib/unity-settings-daemon-1.0/libmedia-keys.so.backup
   sudo rm /usr/lib/unity-settings-daemon-1.0/libmedia-keys.so
   sudo cp ./plugins/media-keys/.libs/libmedia-keys.so /usr/lib/unity-settings-daemon-1.0/libmedia-keys.so
   restart unity-settings-daemon
   ```

---

**How did I find it:**

1. `dbus-monitor`
2. Click on volume media key, watch for the sender of notification call
3. You may see only as number (Ex: `:1.14`), use `qdbusviewer` to know name:

   ```
   method call sender=:1.14 -> dest=:1.107 serial=176 path=/org/freedesktop/Notifications; interface=org.freedesktop.Notifications; member=Notify
      string "gnome-settings-daemon"
      uint32 0
      string "notification-audio-volume-medium"
      string " "
      string ""
      array [
      ]
      array [
         dict entry(
            string "x-canonical-private-synchronous"
            variant             string "volume"
         )
         dict entry(
            string "value"
            variant             int32 44
         )
      ]
      int32 -1
   ```
4. Now, you get the related package, report a bug!!! Changing Code is just an art, try it yourself. I'm not an alien.

Answer (score 0):

Install [`NotifyOSDConfig`](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/webupd8/trusty/main/base/notifyosdconfig), the GUI used to configure the NotifyOSD.

Then lets add [it's PPA](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/ppa/webupd8?dist=trusty). Open a Terminal and type the command.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
```

Next update list and start installation

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install notifyosdconfig
```

And How did I disable it?

Launch `NotifyOSD Configuration` from Dash and as you see in screenshot you need to change "**Width**" and "**Corner Radius**" to "**0 px**" and then click **Apply**.

[image]

Enjoy ;)

Comment: Wait, won't this disable *all* notification bubbles? I don't see anything in this answer that should make this apply only to volume notifications.

Answer (score 0):

I found that (on Xubuntu) I was able to use `xfce4-notifyd-config` (located in settings>notifications) and navigate to the Applications tab to disable the `xfce volume daemon` from sending notifications. I'm unsure of the GNOME equivalent to this fix.

---

Attatched is an image of the UI:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/EGPBQ.jpg