# Hide or remove GNOME pop-up for sound volume level indicator

Tags: 18.04, gnome-shell

When I scroll the mouse over the volume control a volume level indicator is shown in the center of screen.

[image]

How can I remove this pop-up sound volume level indicator?

Answer (score 5):

It's a built-in "feature" of GNOME shell, so it's probably not easily removable by default. You may use a [GNOME extension](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75530/how-do-i-install-and-manage-gnome-shell-extensions) called "[Better OSD](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1345/better-osd/)" as a workaround. This allows you to reposition and resize OSD pop-ups like the volume pop-up you have mentioned.

[image]

It also has a "**Hide Delay**" option, setting it to "0" should make the pop-up invisible.

Answer (score 0):

**Move OSD Windows** extension can hide them altogether instead of moving it.

https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1220/move-osd-windows

[image: Move OSD Windows]